# Event that would "setState" when div becomes visible in amp-html

Tags: html, amp-html

To begin, I understand how to `setState` in amp-html using amp-bind like so:

```
<amp-selector on="select:AMP.setState({ guess: event.targetOption })">
    <div class="button" option="a">Answer 1</div>
    <div class="button" option="b">Answer 2</div>
    <div class="button" option="c">Answer 3</div>
</amp-selector>
```

Now say I select the button `Answer 2`, then the state upon `printState()` will look like `{"guess":"b"}` and this div will no longer be hidden:

```
<div hidden [hidden]="!guess">
    <h4>You have the correct answer!</h4>
</div>
```

**My question is**: How do I set another key/value to state once the hidden div becomes visible? In other words, how can I get this to work?

```
<div hidden [hidden]="!guess" on="WhenThisIsVisible:AMP.setState({"text":"hi!"})"></div>
```

I can use `tap:` instead of my made-up event, but I'd like to not have the user have to click on the div to `setState`.

So once the div is visible, `printState()` would return `{"guess":"b","text":"hi!"}`

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use a `span` inside the div, and then using something like:

```
<span [text]="text"></span>
```

Here is the complete sample:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AMP Page</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-selector" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-selector-0.1.js"></script>
  <style amp-custom>
    h1 {
      margin: 1rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <amp-selector on="select:AMP.setState({ guess: event.targetOption, text: 'hi' })">
    <div class="button" option="a">Answer 1</div>
    <div class="button" option="b">Answer 2</div>
    <div class="button" option="c">Answer 3</div>
</amp-selector>
  <div hidden [hidden]="!guess">
    <span [text]="text"></span>
    <h4>You have the correct answer!</h4>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure how this relates to setting the amp state